# Grouping words with same meaning. in LDA

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I would like to know if it is possible to group together same words included in the LDA's output, i.e. words generated by

```
doc_lda = lda_model[corpus]
```

for example

```
[(0,
  '0.084*"tourism" + 0.013*"touristic" + 0.013*"Madrid" + '
  '0.010*"travel" + 0.008*"half" + 0.007*"piare" + '
  '0.007*"turism"')]
```

I would like to group `tourism, touristic` and `turism` (mispelled) together.
Would it be possible?

This is some relevant previous code:

```
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=num_topics, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha=[0.01]*num_topics,
                                           per_word_topics=True,
                                           eta=[0.01]*len(id2word.keys()))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to understand is LDA requires a great deal of tuning and iteration to work properly unlike say linear regression. But it can be useful for a certain set of problems.

Your intuition is right in that 'tourism', 'touristic' and 'turism' should all be one word. The fix, however, is not at the end where you are presented with their respective loadings but rather, early on with stemming and lemmatization (aka, stemming and lemming), adding unwanted words to your stopwords list, and some preprocessing to some degree or another. I'll address them separately but not as a group as I think that's fairly obvious. Also, because you only gave the one set of words and loadings, it's not really fruitful to go into providing the number of topics as you may be doing that just fine.

**Stemming/Lemming (Pick One)**

This is where the science and experience part starts, as well as the frustration. But, this is where you'll make the biggest and easiest gains. It seems like 'tourism' and 'touristic' might be best combined by stemming (as tour). The truth is a lot less clear cut as there are cases where one beats the other. In the below example, PortaStemer suffers from making sensible stems but lemmatizing fails to catch how 'studies' and studying are the same though it accurately catches 'cry'.

```
Using PorterStemer
studies is studi
studying is studi
cries is cri
cry is cri

Lemmatize
studies is study
studying is studying
cries is cry
cry is cry
```

There are multiple stemmers such as Porter2, Snowball, Hunspell, and Paice-Husk. So, the obvious first step would be to see if any of these is more useful out of the box.

As mentioned above, lemmatization will get you a similar -- but somewhat different -- set of results.

There is no substitute for the work here. This is what separates a data scientist from a hobbiest or data analyst with plussed up title. The best time to do this was in the past so you would have an intuition of what works best for this sort of corpus; the second-best time is now.

**Iterate But Satisfice**

I presume you don't have infinite resources; you have to [satisfice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing). For the above, you might consider preprocessing your text to correct or remove misspelled words. What to do with non-English words is trickier. The easiest solution is to remove them or add them to your stopwords list but that may not be the best solution. Customizing your dictionary is an option too.

**Know The Current Limits**

As of 2020, *no one* is doing a good job with [codeswitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching); certainly not a free and opensource resource. Gridspace is about the best I know of, and while their [demo is pretty amazing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xu0OKD3UL_k), they can't handle codeswitching well.  Now, I'm doing some induction here because I'm assuming 'piare' is Spanish for 'I will', at least that what google translate says. If that's the case, your results will be confounded. But when you look at the loading (.007) that seems to be more work than would be worth it.